# Rename associated Figure files

Tags: floats, external-files, archiving

Some journals request that the submitted figure files are named to match the compiled latex pdf (fig1.pdf, fig2.pdf, ...). Now most of my colleagues and I do not name our figures according to the numbering in the latex document, but to what's in them (e.g. experiment1_time_vs_location.pdf). Is there an easy way to have a script rename them (or hard link them) so that it is easier for submission for OSX and Linux. How do you access the figure numbers generated by Latex?

Comment: Probably but it depends on (1) your operating system, (2) the details of your file names and/or inclusion commands. On GNU/Linux, OS X or similar, a combination of `grep`, `sed` and/or `gawk` should probably do it. But it is impossible to say anything more on the basis of the information you've provided.

Comment: I think that in its present form this question is Off-Topic here; it's not about typesetting using (La)TeX or friends.

Comment: @gonzaloMedina It is not clear to me why this is an off topic question. The information needed (Figure numbers) are generated by Latex. Bundling of latex projects in certain ways for journals is a very common task for people that use this type setting system. Furthermore, there is a cornucopia of questions that aim at a similar direction of dealing with external files (e.g. questions/152765, questions/12554). Finally, this post has gotten an up vote and seems interesting to the community. I respectfully ask that this question be resumed.

Comment: @cfr I have added OSX and Linux as the OS.

Comment: It is off-topic because the best solution is probably a script, as you suggested yourself, and that is outside the scope of this site. Many scripts are useful to people who use TeX etc. and TeX distributions include some of them. But the content of such a script is not a matter for TeX - it is bash or perl or python or whatever. Moreover, the question cannot be answered in its current form as I explained in my earlier comment. It narrows it down a little to know the target OSs but not enough to say anything beyond: definitely look at `sed`, `grep` and/or `gawk`.

Comment: I disagree, it's on topic. LaTeX comes with a lot of scripts to help you. Also there are also "pure"-(La)TeX solutions (with write18) possible. Reopening it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks for reopening it. You suggest a solution with write18. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible via the `external` library of TikZ and documented in the manual.

You can either embed your external pictures inside a node inside a TikZ picture and externalize that or you can see the `png export` example in the manual (section 50.7 in the manual of version TikZ 3.0.0)